# Architect website/mobile notifications generated by users activities

Tags: push-notification, architecture, notifications

I am working on a mobile application, this application has some features like users can follow each others,  adding comments or reviews, like something .. etc.

So the requirement is we have notifications icon in the app, when the user click on it a list of notification will show up, taken in consider those notifications should be real time.

Many things comes to my mind will reviewing this feature, like using firebase to send the notification, or I can develop internal notification service for this purpose.

The question is what do you suggest guys, do you think using firebase is a good idea for such case? or there is something else you recommend for such case

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try signalR more manageable than firebase but you need to know programing to manage signalR

Comment: Sory u don't tell anything about what u re using